# c# struct to IntPtr gives System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pointers

I'm using a DLL that has function definition :

```
public J2534Err PassThruIoctl(int channelId, int ioctlID, IntPtr input, IntPtr output)
```

There is a working vb program :

```
Public Type SCONFIG_LIST
    NumOfParams As Long
    ConfigPtr As Long
End Type
Public Type SCONFIG
    Parameter As Long
    Value As Long
End Type

Dim sCfg As SCONFIG, sCfgList As SCONFIG_LIST
sCfg.Parameter = J1962_PINS
sCfg.Value = J2534Prot(lProtIndex).PinsValue
sCfgList.NumOfParams = 1
sCfgList.ConfigPtr = VarPtr(sCfg) lResult = PassThruIoctl(J2534Boxes(lSelectedBox).Channel(lProtIndex).ChID, SET_CONFIG, sCfgList, ByVal 0&)
```

I want to call this function in C#

The following compiles , but gives System.AccessViolationException

```
private IntPtr objectToIntptr(object o)
{
     GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(o, GCHandleType.Pinned);
     return handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
}

SConfig sCfg;
SConfigList sCfgList = new SConfigList();

sCfg.Parameter = ConfigParameter.J1962_PINS;
sCfg.Value = 0xff;

sCfgList.Count = 1;
sCfgList.ListPtr = objectToIntptr(sCfg);

m_status = m_j2534Interface.PassThruIoctl(m_channelId, (int)Ioctl.SET_CONFIG, objectToIntptr(sCfg), IntPtr.Zero);
```

Also tried some code snippets i found using marshall.
But it either won't compile, or errors on AccessViolationException.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_status = m_j2534Interface.PassThruIoctl(m_channelId, (int)Ioctl.SET_CONFIG, objectToIntptr(sCfg), IntPtr.Zero);
```

should be

```
m_status = m_j2534Interface.PassThruIoctl(m_channelId, (int)Ioctl.SET_CONFIG, objectToIntptr(sCfgList), IntPtr.Zero);
```

I was passing the wrong var.. 
looking for hours , and 10 min after posting :-(

@dan

```
  public struct SConfigList
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public IntPtr ListPtr { get; set; }

    public List<SConfig> GetList()
    {
        if (ListPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
            return new List<SConfig>();
        return ListPtr.AsList<SConfig>(Count);
    }
}
```

I'm guess there must be a cleaner way to do, what i'm doing.